# Nginx React App on Google Cloud Run does not start and ready condition status changes to false

Tags: reactjs, docker, nginx, google-cloud-run

I have a react app deployed on cloud run with nginx as the webserver.
For the setup I followed the guide [here](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/easy-serverless-deployment-of-your-react-app-using-cloud-run-c26aa79af491)
The docker set up runs perfectly fine on the local but it errors out on cloud run.

[image]

Here's the dockerfile and nginx config.

Dockerfile

```
# Name the node stage "builder"
FROM node:18-alpine AS builder

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /app

# Copy our node module specification
COPY package.json package.json
COPY yarn.lock yarn.lock

# install node modules and build assets
RUN yarn install --production

# Copy all files from current directory to working dir in image
# Except the one defined in '.dockerignore'
COPY . .

# Create production build of React App
RUN yarn build

# Choose NGINX as our base Docker image
FROM nginx:alpine

# Copy our nginx configuration
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/configfile.template
COPY ./environments/.env.final /usr/share/nginx/html/.env

RUN apk add --update nodejs
RUN apk add --update npm
RUN npm install -g runtime-env-cra@0.2.4

# Set working directory to nginx asset directory
WORKDIR /usr/share/nginx/html

# Remove default nginx static assets
RUN rm -rf *

# Copy static assets from builder stage
COPY --from=builder /app/build .

# Define environment variables for Cloud Run
ENV PORT 8080
ENV HOST 0.0.0.0
EXPOSE 8080
# Substitute $PORT variable in config file with the one passed via "docker run"
CMD sh -c "envsubst '\$PORT' < /etc/nginx/conf.d/configfile.template > /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf && runtime-env-cra  && nginx -g 'daemon off;' && lsof -i:8080"
```

Nginx.conf

```
    server {
     # $PORT will be provided by 'docker run'
     listen       $PORT;
     server_name  localhost;
     error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log debug;
     location / {
         root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
         index  index.html index.htm;
         try_files $uri /index.html;
     }

     gzip on;
     gzip_vary on;
     gzip_min_length 10240;
     gzip_proxied expired no-cache no-store private auth;
     gzip_types text/plain text/css text/xml text/javascript application/x-javascript application/xml;
     gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.";
}
```

To get more debugging information related to nginx I then used nginx-debug instead of nginx to run my app. Here are the logs. It's in reverse order. The bottom most log is the first log.

```
2022/04/30 04:51:48 [debug] 22#22: accept() not ready (11: Resource temporarily unavailable),2022-04-30T04:51:48.569382Z,
"2022/04/30 04:51:48 [debug] 21#21: *5 free: 00007FADEA046AE0, unused: 136",2022-04-30T04:51:48.569377Z,
2022/04/30 04:51:48 [debug] 21#21: *5 free: 00007FADEA03F570,2022-04-30T04:51:48.569372Z,
2022/04/30 04:51:48 [debug] 21#21: *5 reusable connection: 0,2022-04-30T04:51:48.569368Z,
2022/04/30 04:51:48 [debug] 21#21: *5 event timer del: 13: 62382,2022-04-30T04:51:48.569362Z,
2022/04/30 04:51:48 [debug] 21#21: *5 close http connection: 13,2022-04-30T04:51:48.569358Z,
"2022/04/30 04:51:48 [info] 21#21: *5 client closed connection while waiting for request, client: 169.254.1.1, server: 0.0.0.0:8080",2022-04-30T04:51:48.569352Z,
2022/04/30 04:51:48 [debug] 21#21: *5 recv: fd:13 0 of 1024,2022-04-30T04:51:48.569347Z,
"2022/04/30 04:51:48 [debug] 21#21: *5 recv: eof:1, avail:-1",2022-04-30T04:51:48.569342Z,
2022/04/30 04:51:48 [debug] 21#21: *5 malloc: 00007FADEA03F570:1024,2022-04-30T04:51:48.569338Z,
2022/04/30 04:51:48 [debug] 21#21: *5 http wait request handler,2022-04-30T04:51:48.569332Z,
"2022/04/30 04:51:48 [debug] 21#21: *4 free: 00007FADEA046D50, unused: 136",2022-04-30T04:51:48.569327Z,
2022/04/30 04:51:48 [debug] 21#21: *4 free: 00007FADEA03FAE0,2022-04-30T04:51:48.569322Z,
2022/04/30 04:51:48 [debug] 21#21: *4 reusable connection: 0,2022-04-30T04:51:48.569316Z,
2022/04/30 04:51:48 [debug] 21#21: *4 event timer del: 12: 62382,2022-04-30T04:51:48.569312Z,
2022/04/30 04:51:48 [debug] 21#21: *4 close http connection: 12,2022-04-30T04:51:48.569307Z,
"2022/04/30 04:51:48 [info] 21#21: *4 client closed connection while waiting for request, client: 169.254.1.1, server: 0.0.0.0:8080",2022-04-30T04:51:48.569302Z,
2022/04/30 04:51:48 [debug] 21#21: *4 recv: fd:12 0 of 1024,2022-04-30T04:51:48.569296Z,
"2022/04/30 04:51:48 [debug] 21#21: *4 recv: eof:1, avail:-1",2022-04-30T04:51:48.569291Z,
2022/04/30 04:51:48 [debug] 21#21: *4 malloc: 00007FADEA03FAE0:1024,2022-04-30T04:51:48.569286Z,
2022/04/30 04:51:48 [debug] 21#21: *4 http wait request handler,2022-04-30T04:51:48.569281Z,
2022/04/30 04:51:48 [debug] 21#21: *5 epoll add event: fd:13 op:1 ev:80002001,2022-04-30T04:51:48.569276Z,
2022/04/30 04:51:48 [debug] 21#21: *5 reusable connection: 1,2022-04-30T04:51:48.569270Z,
2022/04/30 04:51:48 [debug] 21#21: *5 event timer add: 13: 60000:62382,2022-04-30T04:51:48.569265Z,
2022/04/30 04:51:48 [debug] 21#21: *5 accept: 169.254.1.1:61453 fd:13,2022-04-30T04:51:48.569260Z,
2022/04/30 04:51:48 [debug] 21#21: posix_memalign: 00007FADEA046AE0:512 @16,2022-04-30T04:51:48.569255Z,
"2022/04/30 04:51:48 [debug] 21#21: accept on 0.0.0.0:8080, ready: 0",2022-04-30T04:51:48.569248Z,
2022/04/30 04:51:48 [debug] 21#21: *4 epoll add event: fd:12 op:1 ev:80002001,2022-04-30T04:51:48.569244Z,
2022/04/30 04:51:48 [debug] 21#21: *4 reusable connection: 1,2022-04-30T04:51:48.569239Z,
2022/04/30 04:51:48 [debug] 21#21: *4 event timer add: 12: 60000:62382,2022-04-30T04:51:48.569233Z,
2022/04/30 04:51:48 [debug] 21#21: *4 accept: 169.254.1.1:56829 fd:12,2022-04-30T04:51:48.569228Z,
2022/04/30 04:51:48 [debug] 21#21: posix_memalign: 00007FADEA046D50:512 @16,2022-04-30T04:51:48.569222Z,
"2022/04/30 04:51:48 [debug] 21#21: accept on 0.0.0.0:8080, ready: 0",2022-04-30T04:51:48.569216Z,
"2022/04/30 04:51:48 [debug] 22#22: accept on 0.0.0.0:8080, ready: 0",2022-04-30T04:51:48.569196Z,
"2022/04/30 04:51:48 [debug] 21#21: *3 free: 00007FADEA046AD0, unused: 136",2022-04-30T04:51:48.494728Z,
2022/04/30 04:51:48 [debug] 21#21: *3 free: 00007FADEA03F560,2022-04-30T04:51:48.494720Z,
2022/04/30 04:51:48 [debug] 21#21: *3 reusable connection: 0,2022-04-30T04:51:48.494714Z,
2022/04/30 04:51:48 [debug] 21#21: *3 event timer del: 12: 62307,2022-04-30T04:51:48.494708Z,
2022/04/30 04:51:48 [debug] 21#21: *3 close http connection: 12,2022-04-30T04:51:48.494701Z,
"2022/04/30 04:51:48 [info] 21#21: *3 client closed connection while waiting for request, client: 169.254.1.1, server: 0.0.0.0:8080",2022-04-30T04:51:48.494691Z,
2022/04/30 04:51:48 [debug] 21#21: *3 recv: fd:12 0 of 1024,2022-04-30T04:51:48.494682Z,
"2022/04/30 04:51:48 [debug] 21#21: *3 recv: eof:1, avail:-1",2022-04-30T04:51:48.494673Z,
2022/04/30 04:51:48 [debug] 21#21: *3 malloc: 00007FADEA03F560:1024,2022-04-30T04:51:48.494665Z,
2022/04/30 04:51:48 [debug] 21#21: *3 http wait request handler,2022-04-30T04:51:48.494657Z,
2022/04/30 04:51:48 [debug] 21#21: epoll add event: fd:7 op:1 ev:10000001,2022-04-30T04:51:48.494648Z,
2022/04/30 04:51:48 [debug] 21#21: epoll del event: fd:7 op:2 ev:00000000,2022-04-30T04:51:48.494634Z,
2022/04/30 04:51:48 [debug] 21#21: *3 epoll add event: fd:12 op:1 ev:80002001,2022-04-30T04:51:48.494625Z,
2022/04/30 04:51:48 [debug] 21#21: *3 reusable connection: 1,2022-04-30T04:51:48.494613Z,
2022/04/30 04:51:48 [debug] 21#21: *3 event timer add: 12: 60000:62307,2022-04-30T04:51:48.494603Z,
2022/04/30 04:51:48 [debug] 21#21: *3 accept: 169.254.1.1:50168 fd:12,2022-04-30T04:51:48.494593Z,
2022/04/30 04:51:48 [debug] 21#21: posix_memalign: 00007FADEA046AD0:512 @16,2022-04-30T04:51:48.494562Z,
"2022/04/30 04:51:48 [debug] 21#21: accept on 0.0.0.0:8080, ready: 0",2022-04-30T04:51:48.494539Z,
"2022/04/30 04:51:48 [debug] 22#22: *2 free: 00007FADEA046D50, unused: 136",2022-04-30T04:51:48.491920Z,
2022/04/30 04:51:48 [debug] 22#22: *2 free: 00007FADEA03FAE0,2022-04-30T04:51:48.491915Z,
2022/04/30 04:51:48 [debug] 22#22: *2 reusable connection: 0,2022-04-30T04:51:48.491909Z,
2022/04/30 04:51:48 [debug] 22#22: *2 event timer del: 8: 62304,2022-04-30T04:51:48.491904Z,
2022/04/30 04:51:48 [debug] 22#22: *2 close http connection: 8,2022-04-30T04:51:48.491899Z,
"2022/04/30 04:51:48 [info] 22#22: *2 client closed connection while waiting for request, client: 169.254.1.1, server: 0.0.0.0:8080",2022-04-30T04:51:48.491893Z,
2022/04/30 04:51:48 [debug] 22#22: *2 recv: fd:8 0 of 1024,2022-04-30T04:51:48.491886Z,
"2022/04/30 04:51:48 [debug] 22#22: *2 recv: eof:1, avail:-1",2022-04-30T04:51:48.491881Z,
2022/04/30 04:51:48 [debug] 22#22: *2 malloc: 00007FADEA03FAE0:1024,2022-04-30T04:51:48.491876Z,
2022/04/30 04:51:48 [debug] 22#22: *2 http wait request handler,2022-04-30T04:51:48.491869Z,
2022/04/30 04:51:48 [debug] 22#22: *2 epoll add event: fd:8 op:1 ev:80002001,2022-04-30T04:51:48.491864Z,
2022/04/30 04:51:48 [debug] 22#22: *2 reusable connection: 1,2022-04-30T04:51:48.491859Z,
2022/04/30 04:51:48 [debug] 22#22: *2 event timer add: 8: 60000:62304,2022-04-30T04:51:48.491854Z,
2022/04/30 04:51:48 [debug] 22#22: *2 accept: 169.254.1.1:18005 fd:8,2022-04-30T04:51:48.491849Z,
2022/04/30 04:51:48 [debug] 22#22: posix_memalign: 00007FADEA046D50:512 @16,2022-04-30T04:51:48.491844Z,
"2022/04/30 04:51:48 [debug] 22#22: accept on 0.0.0.0:8080, ready: 0",2022-04-30T04:51:48.491839Z,
"2022/04/30 04:51:48 [debug] 22#22: *1 free: 00007FADEA046AD0, unused: 136",2022-04-30T04:51:48.491834Z,
2022/04/30 04:51:48 [debug] 22#22: *1 free: 00007FADEA03F560,2022-04-30T04:51:48.491828Z,
2022/04/30 04:51:48 [debug] 22#22: *1 reusable connection: 0,2022-04-30T04:51:48.491820Z,
2022/04/30 04:51:48 [debug] 22#22: *1 event timer del: 8: 62304,2022-04-30T04:51:48.491813Z,
2022/04/30 04:51:48 [debug] 22#22: *1 close http connection: 8,2022-04-30T04:51:48.491805Z,
"2022/04/30 04:51:48 [info] 22#22: *1 client closed connection while waiting for request, client: 169.254.1.1, server: 0.0.0.0:8080",2022-04-30T04:51:48.491798Z,
2022/04/30 04:51:48 [debug] 22#22: *1 recv: fd:8 0 of 1024,2022-04-30T04:51:48.491791Z,
"2022/04/30 04:51:48 [debug] 22#22: *1 recv: eof:1, avail:-1",2022-04-30T04:51:48.491783Z,
2022/04/30 04:51:48 [debug] 22#22: *1 malloc: 00007FADEA03F560:1024,2022-04-30T04:51:48.491776Z,
2022/04/30 04:51:48 [debug] 22#22: *1 http wait request handler,2022-04-30T04:51:48.491754Z,
2022/04/30 04:51:48 [debug] 22#22: epoll add event: fd:7 op:1 ev:10000001,2022-04-30T04:51:48.491746Z,
2022/04/30 04:51:48 [debug] 22#22: epoll del event: fd:7 op:2 ev:00000000,2022-04-30T04:51:48.491740Z,
2022/04/30 04:51:48 [debug] 22#22: *1 epoll add event: fd:8 op:1 ev:80002001,2022-04-30T04:51:48.491733Z,
2022/04/30 04:51:48 [debug] 22#22: *1 reusable connection: 1,2022-04-30T04:51:48.491725Z,
2022/04/30 04:51:48 [debug] 22#22: *1 event timer add: 8: 60000:62304,2022-04-30T04:51:48.491718Z,
2022/04/30 04:51:48 [debug] 22#22: *1 accept: 169.254.1.1:31598 fd:8,2022-04-30T04:51:48.491711Z,
2022/04/30 04:51:48 [debug] 22#22: posix_memalign: 00007FADEA046AD0:512 @16,2022-04-30T04:51:48.491703Z,
"2022/04/30 04:51:48 [debug] 22#22: accept on 0.0.0.0:8080, ready: 0",2022-04-30T04:51:48.491682Z,
2022/04/30 04:51:48 [debug] 22#22: epoll add event: fd:7 op:1 ev:10000001,2022-04-30T04:51:48.486691Z,
2022/04/30 04:51:48 [debug] 21#21: epoll add event: fd:7 op:1 ev:10000001,2022-04-30T04:51:48.486669Z,
2022/04/30 04:51:48 [notice] 20#20: start worker process 22,2022-04-30T04:51:48.485982Z,
2022/04/30 04:51:48 [notice] 20#20: start worker process 21,2022-04-30T04:51:48.485857Z,
2022/04/30 04:51:48 [notice] 20#20: start worker processes,2022-04-30T04:51:48.485713Z,
2022/04/30 04:51:48 [notice] 20#20: getrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE): 1024:4096,2022-04-30T04:51:48.485662Z,
2022/04/30 04:51:48 [notice] 20#20: OS: Linux 5.8.9,2022-04-30T04:51:48.485656Z,
"2022/04/30 04:51:48 [notice] 20#20: built by gcc 10.3.1 20211027 (Alpine 10.3.1_git20211027) ",2022-04-30T04:51:48.485635Z,
2022/04/30 04:51:48 [notice] 20#20: nginx/1.21.6,2022-04-30T04:51:48.485627Z,
"2022/04/30 04:51:48 [notice] 20#20: using the ""epoll"" event method",2022-04-30T04:51:48.485600Z,
"  ",2022-04-30T04:51:48.421815Z,
"  Thank you for using runtime-env-cra!",2022-04-30T04:51:48.421806Z,
,2022-04-30T04:51:48.421799Z,
"  Result: window.__RUNTIME_CONFIG__ = {"NODE_ENV":"integration"};",2022-04-30T04:51:48.421790Z,
Successfully generated your runtime-env config!,2022-04-30T04:51:48.421768Z,
"  ",2022-04-30T04:51:48.409129Z,
"  Your environment variables will be available on 'window.__RUNTIME_CONFIG__'",2022-04-30T04:51:48.409123Z,
,2022-04-30T04:51:48.409116Z,
"    --env-file = ./.env",2022-04-30T04:51:48.409111Z,
"    --config-name = ./runtime-env.js",2022-04-30T04:51:48.409105Z,
"  Provided flags:",2022-04-30T04:51:48.409096Z,
```

The gist here is that I keep getting `client closed connection while waiting for request`. Any pointers on how to fix this? I don't understand the reason why this is happening.

Comment: This often happens if the `index` file or any other file has a missing directory. can you check it once